# Whether it will be faster if we are storing information into excel file and then reading it and writing the file into a table in postgre

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I'm using a query where a for loop is used to generate an result for more than 1.000 rows. For each and every loop im inserting the result into a table. It takes some time for inserting this.

So I have an idea to use `COPY` command to write the result into an Excel file and after the entire for loop is over im going to use the `COPY` command to write from excel to the table. Please any one suggest whether it will be faster than the first way.

Comment: Have your tried it? What was the result?

Comment: Using Excel might be faster if you are using PostgreSQL incorrectly, but it is definitely non-standard usage. You should maybe ask different question on how to speed up your loops in PostgreSQL directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If used correctly, Postgres will be *much* faster.

However, if you're more skilled in Excel and it's easier for you to do this in Excel than it might still be the better option for you.

Without more info about what you are trying to do, your tables and more... can't really help you.